# Help on how to even get started with OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript

I am tired of looking. I can't even get a pin to drop on one of these maps why is it so complex to do something simple? Okay, enough whining I have found plenty of information on the 2.0 beta blah blah but what about this new version with the different UI (3.1). Please, someone, point me in the right direction for help or for everyone's sake that hasn't been using the last 75 versions make a tutorial. Thank you in advanced from stopping my head from exploding and for my wife not divorcing me.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  It would be easier to help you out if your could provide some code and settings of the most recent thing you have tried. Also which version of Drupal are you using, and what other tools are involved in your solution?